# Эффект 3д + паралакс

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, wordpress

Всем привет, хотел бы спросить как сделать так же как на этом сайте https://advanced.team/
а именно когда при скроле буква а в 3д увеличивается и потом резко переходит на дальше инфу, если кто шарит помогите по-мему эффект используется паралакс, я просто не могу понять как они сделали, меня интересует больше 3д буква а и при скроле она увеличивается + открывается видео ролик

Comment: Судя по id="three-js", они используют данную библиотеку. Вот ссылка для ознакомления https://threejs.org

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за библиотеку, почитаю)

Comment: Кто нибудь еще что-то подскажет?